# Map a table with a flattened collection back to a collection

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've got a table that I'm wanting to manually map via code-first for some read-only lookups.  Currently the table has several sets of columns such as AGENT1_PROPERTY, AGENT1_PROPERTY2...AGENTX_PROPERTY1 is it possible to map these back to a array such that I have a property of AGENTS[X] on my entity?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in EF that isn't way more work than it's worth.  You could use a [Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions), or map a view as a [Keyless Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types).  But it will be easier to just map the Entity into a custom type and use that.